# How to remove identity's endpoint?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a MVC project which was created via `Identity` template. I decided to remove default `Identity` from my app, then I removed whole `Areas` folder.

> /Identity/Account/Manage

Now I'm not sure why this endpoint returns

> Unable to load user with ID '{guid}'.

Meanwhile e.g `/Identity/Account/` returns blank page *(which's my goal)*

I tried to scan all project files for key words like `Unable to`, but it is not there. Any ideas on how to remove that endpoint?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would help if you could post a part of your account/ identity controller. 
It looks like you have a route set that accepts a guid as parameter.

Comment: @Immorality But I do not have ``Account`` nor ``Identity`` Controller

Comment: This may sound silly but... did you recompile the application?

Comment: @JuanR I even killed IIS, removed obj and bin folders and e.g ``/Identity/Account/`` returns blank page but

    ``/Identity/Account/Manage`` returns that message, maybe ``services.AddDefaultIdentity`` does way more behind the scenes.

Comment: I suspect error you are seeing is not coming from where you think. I would suggest searching for the string `Unable to load user with ID`. It will shed some light as to what is loading it.

Comment: @JuanR I did that: ``I tried to scan all project files for key words like "Unable to," but it is not there``

Comment: Do yo have any other applications runningn on IIS?

Comment: addDefaultIdentity() adds default pages. Use addIdentity() instead. See e.g. https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1824

Comment: Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

For removing Identity, you need to remove `Areas` Folder and comment out `services.AddDefaultIdentity`.

For Identity, it uses Identity Razor library, which complies the View Into library. That means, it would not remove Identity View if you only delete the `Areas`.

> Unable to load user with ID '{guid}'.

For this error, it is defined in [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.V4.Pages.Account.Manage.Internal](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/9b385180a9abcb264507efc23279f083bfc50520/src/UI/Areas/Identity/Pages/V4/Account/Manage/Index.cshtml.cs#L67)

> Meanwhile e.g /Identity/Account/ returns blank page (which's my goal)

If you only replace the content for `/Identity/Account/`, you could custom the view for `Areas\Identity\Pages\Account\Manage\_Layout.cshtml`.

Create such file and replace the content with below:

```
@{ 
   Layout = "/Areas/Identity/Pages/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@section Scripts {
     @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
}
```

**For a quick soltuion**, I would suggest you try `Middleware` like below:

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.Map("/Identity/Account", map =>
        {
            map.Run(async context =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("");
            });
        });
```